# Insert hyperlink with javascript bootstrap

Tags: javascript

```
<div class="cover" style="background-image: url({THEME}/images/tmp/tamtranghangnga_748x360.gif);"></div>

</div>
```

How to insert the hyperlink with the image used background as .gif above with this code. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

I dont know what's outputting the THEME variable but do you mean something like this?

```
<a href="{THEME}/images/tmp/tamtranghangnga_748x360.gif">
    <div class="cover" style="background-image: url({THEME}/images/tmp/tamtranghangnga_748x360.gif);"></div>
</div></a>
```

Comment: I just change some minor code and it work <a href="{THEME}/images/tmp/tamtranghangnga_748x360.gif"><img src="{THEME}/images/tmp/tamtranghangnga_748x360.gif">
    <div class="cover" style="background-image: url({THEME}/images/tmp/tamtranghangnga_748x360.gif);"></div>
</div></a>

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `<div>` inside an `<a>` tag. Like this:

```
<a href="/templates/Default/images/tmp/trimun_748x360.gif">
  <div class="cover" style="background-image: url({THEME}/images/tmp/tamtranghangnga_748x360.gif);"></div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks you so much but the carouse don't load the image after I put the hyperlink onto. You can visit my site here for more info http://aucospa.com/

Comment: I looked at your site, and the image url is not right. I updated the answer, try this.

Answer (score -1):

W3 Schools is the best place to go for learning about many things including Bootstrap, this is an example from there (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp)

```
body {
background-image: url("image.gif");
background-color: #cccccc;
```

}

Comment: this is not the answer to the question asked.